# Does MYSQL Support Object Oriented Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Does MYSQL support Object Oriented Database or just Relational Databases?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately not, as far as i know MySQL doesn't have any way of storing Objects in a nice way except for blobs , which aren't really nice in my honest opinion :)

Answer (score 5):

MySQL is a relational database rather than an object oriented database.

You can use a database such as MySQL in an object oriented manner from your code using an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) library. A good example of this is Doctrine for PHP. 
http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Object Oriented databases aren't really in fashion at the moment. Relational Databases are by far the most popular with NoSQL also making some waves.

If you are determined to use an OODB Wikipedia has a list of Object oriented databases you may want to look into
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object_database_management_systems

Comment: OODB and NoSQL aren't exactly mutually exclusive. I assume you didn't mean that, but it sounds a bit like you did.

Comment: Correct I was trying to differentiate between the earlier OODBs which didn't get much traction and the more recent NoSQL movement.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard added (long time ago) the ability to have complex, user-defined types as either attributes of a table or rows of a table (so-called typed tables). These are sometimes known as 'object relational' extensions or similar. Most commercial RDBMS (Oracle, SQL server, DB2, etc.) support these -so does Postgres. However, MySQL does not, as far as I know (last I checked was version 5.7). There are other things added to the standard, though, like support for XML and Json types. MySQL does support Json and has (very) limited support for XML. Pure object oriented databases did come and go and they are nowadays 'niche' products, as far as I know. As for NoSQL, it's more about distributed setup and lack of schema than a particular data model -there is, in fact, no such thing